# VPN blocking internet access on my CentOS

Tags: vpn, centos-8, forticlient

I am using CentOS 8 and for some projects I need to connect on a
FortiClient VPN. It seems that the configuration of the VPN is blocking my machine to have any internet access other than the VPN.

I cannot change FortiClient configuration, I think it is configured from the VPN admin.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a second network interface for my NIC card (my machine has one NIC card), or for my Wi-Fi, and use one interface to connect to VPN and the other to connect to internet.

My curiosity is totally academic. I want to know how flexible can linux be and how it can override some obstacles

Comment: Is this a business or work project and are the "VPN admins" your employer or their delegates? If so, this question is off topic here on Superuser as you are asking for assistance circumventing your employer's controls.

Comment: The vpn is controlled from 3d-party partner and we can not change its settings. I am asking I can through my os for example create a second interface to use it for internet access and my first still using it for vpn. I think this is in the topic.

Comment: If you are required to us this VPN and the 3rd party is allowed to configure and control it, then you are asking us to assist you in circumventing legitimate controls. If the controls were illegitimate, the correct solution would be to use a different VPN tool or provider

Comment: Well I don't see why they are stopping my pc from accessing the internet. My pc is not their property nor is the project. The just host the live application. To work on this project I have to signout from vpn whenever I need to google something and sign in again. I need some help here.

Comment: You don't get it. If the system is actually unnecessary, then don't use it. Because you are clearly not going to not use the system, this means you know or admit it is necessary. We cannot assist you with disabling or circumventing controls you have already accepted yourself.

Comment: Sorry I dont get it. I want to bypass a contstraint implied to me without giving me any other option. But It's my decision and my problem If  I want to bypass it.  So If you don't want to help me then don't.

Comment: It stopped being your decision when you signed up to work for a company that requires certain policies on the computer you use to work for them. Your decision was to work under those conditions. If you want your choice back, stop working for them. We do not assist in circumventing legally binding restrictions.

Comment: Actually the restrictions are on the network interface connecting on their VPN not my whole machine.